# Excel VBA Split Column at Certain Length into Multiple Rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet with columns from A:H. I need to split column H every 60 characters into a new row and copy A:G into these new rows.

Here's how the data is and how I want it:

[image: Picture of data https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVt25.png]

In a perfect world there would be a column at the start that would count each row for each message. So column `A1` would be `1`, `A2` would be `2`, `A3` would be `1`, `A4` would be `2`, etc.

There are 29,453 rows that I need to do this to, so manually doing this is not really an option.

Any help, please?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? any code that we can see the problem you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really that difficult.

**First**, store all the log note in an array

**Second**, loop through every log note in the array and for every loop, do a do while loop to insert new row; copy values to new row; splitting the string every 60 characters.

Continue to loop as long as the length of the substring is more than 60.

**Third**, for the spliting of the cell for column H; this can be done by using the Mid Function to display the values based on characer position.

For example, first row we will display from character position 1 to 60

eg. `Mid(subString, 1, 60)`

Whereas for second row we will display from character position 61 onwards

eg. `Mid(subString, 61, Len(subString))`

Then for subsequent do while loops, the second row will display from character position 1 to 60 etc.

> **Info on Mid Function:**
>
> Mid(string, start, length)
>
> string = full original text
>
> start = start position of character
>
> length = length of character
>
> **Info on Cell Offset:**
>
> .Cells(rowNo, colNo).Offset(RowOffset, ColumnOffset)
>
> RowOffset = eg. [1 = 1 row below cell] [-1 = 1 row above cell]
>
> ColumnOffset = eg. [1 = 1 col to the right of cell] [-1 = 1 col to the left of cell]

**Full Solution**

```
Option Explicit

'split every 60 characters new row
Sub SplitEverySixtyChar()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rowNo As Long
    Dim lastRowNo As Long
    Dim arrayLogNote As Variant
    Dim logNote As Variant
    Dim subString As String


    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
    
        'Find last row no
        lastRowNo = (.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    
        'Store all log note in array
        arrayLogNote = .Range("H2:H" & lastRowNo).Value
    
        'Starting row no is 2
        rowNo = 2
    
        For Each logNote In arrayLogNote
    
            subString = CStr(logNote)
        
            Do While Len(subString) > 60
        
                'Insert new row
                .Cells(rowNo, 1).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
            
                'Copy the cell from A:G col into new row
                .Cells(rowNo, 1).Offset(1, 0).Value = .Cells(rowNo, 1).Value
                .Cells(rowNo, 2).Offset(1, 0).Value = .Cells(rowNo, 2).Value
                .Cells(rowNo, 3).Offset(1, 0).Value = .Cells(rowNo, 3).Value
                .Cells(rowNo, 4).Offset(1, 0).Value = .Cells(rowNo, 4).Value
                .Cells(rowNo, 5).Offset(1, 0).Value = .Cells(rowNo, 5).Value
                .Cells(rowNo, 6).Offset(1, 0).Value = .Cells(rowNo, 6).Value
                .Cells(rowNo, 7).Offset(1, 0).Value = .Cells(rowNo, 7).Value
            
                'Display text for new row from character position 60 onwards
                .Cells(rowNo, 8).Offset(1, 0).Value = Mid(subString, 61, Len(subString))
            
                'Display text from character position 1 to 60
                .Cells(rowNo, 8).Value = Mid(subString, 1, 60)
            
                subString = .Cells(rowNo, 8).Offset(1, 0).Value
            
                'Increment Row No
                rowNo = rowNo + 1
            
            Loop
                'Increment Row No
                rowNo = rowNo + 1
        Next logNote
   
    End With

End Sub
```

Note: This is probably not the most efficient solution out there. There are definitely better solution than this.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I should have shown this in my example but a record could need to be split into anywhere between 1 (a note that's 60 or less characters) to 33 (1,980 or less characters) lines. How would I implement this?

Comment: I am also not opposed to having the data show up in a new sheet, if that makes this any easier.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to run the code a few times (it would crash out after ~10k records, I had ~30k) but it worked like a charm. It only missed two rows (I think I might have messed up my cut/paste) and left them with the full-size note. Other then that, amazing! You just saved me so much time.