# VBA split-column-at-certain-length?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question that is almost exactly the same as this thread link below:

[Excel VBA Split Column at Certain Length into Multiple Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45312459/excel-vba-split-column-at-certain-length-into-multiple-rows)

However, what if i'd like to look for the last delimiter before splitting?

example: length requirement is less than 10.

my string is: 11, 3344, 5566 result will be:
Row 1: 11,3344,
Row 2: 5566

basically i dont need to be exactly 10 characters (should be 10 chars at most) but i need to consider the last delimiter before it reaches 10 characters. Kindly help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start at the 1000 character and loop through the text backward to check if the current character is equal to the delimiter that you want, if not continue looping backward. If it is equal to the delimiter, stop the loop and get the position.

```
Sub tester():
    ''Application.SendKeys "^g ^a {DEL}"
    Dim last_ctr As Variant
    Dim current_char As Variant
    Dim final_char As Variant
    Dim limit As Variant
    Dim my_delimiter as Variant

    '' your limit on the text
    limit = 1000
    my_delimiter = ","

    test = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    '' loop backwards from the string
    For x = limit To 0 Step -1
        '' check the current char if it is equal to what you want
        current_char = Mid(test, x, 1)
        If current_char = my_delimiter Then
            '' get the current position of the loop
            final_char = x
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x
    End Sub
```

After retrieving the position `(final_char)` use the `Left` command on it

```
Left(test, final_char)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `Left$(myString, 10)` in to the spliter. Then you are only looking at the first 10 characters and doing the split.